# SFML sending packets using structures not working

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, sfml

So i am trying to get my server to send my client a packet containing an opcode and size but when i send it, it prints out nothing/does not work.

I'm using a structure for the codes the struct is as follows;

```
struct PacketFormatHeader
{
    unsigned short size; // How many bytes are in the data
    unsigned short opcode; // The operation code of this packet
} _packet;
```

Here is my server login.cpp that i send the packet with.

```
#include "NetServer.h"
using namespace net;

Login::Login(void)
{
}

Login::~Login(void)
{
}

sf::Packet& operator <<(sf::Packet& packet, const Packet::PacketFormatHeader& p)
{
    return packet << p.size << p.opcode;
}
sf::Packet& operator >>(sf::Packet& packet, Packet::PacketFormatHeader& p)
{
    return packet >> p.size >> p.opcode;
}

bool Login::CheckAccount()
{
    if(p.IsPlayerBanned() == true) {
        //  DenyLogin();
    }
    if(_checkAccountInUse == true) {
        //DenyLogin();
    }
    return _accountPassed = true;
}

void Login::HandleLogin()
{
    sf::Uint32 x = 12;
    pac._packet.size = x;
    pac._packet.opcode = 1;

    sf::Packet packet;
    sf::Packet& operator <<(sf::Packet& packet, const Packet::PacketFormatHeader& p);
    packet << pac._packet.size << pac._packet.opcode;
    net.client.send(packet);
    util::Logger::Dbg("Login step one passed: Sent first packet: Opcode 1");
}
```

When this is called it created the packet (I hope) and then the client should receive it.
Here is my client network (It's a mess since ive been trying to get this to work for a while)

```
#include "Network.h"

Network::Network(void)
{
}

Network::~Network(void)
{
}

struct PacketFormatHeader
{
    unsigned short size; // How many bytes are in the data
    unsigned short opcode; // The operation code of this packet
} _packet;

sf::Packet& operator <<(sf::Packet& packet, const PacketFormatHeader& p)
{
    return packet << p.size << p.opcode;
}
sf::Packet& operator >>(sf::Packet& packet, PacketFormatHeader& p)
{
    return packet >> p.size >> p.opcode;
}

void Network::InitNetwork(const sf::IpAddress &remoteAdress, int port)
{
    sf::Socket::Status status = socket.connect(remoteAdress, port);

    if (status != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        cout << "Could not connect to server" << endl;
        SetConnected(false);
        RetryConnection("25.196.76.171", 12975);
    } else {
        cout << "Connected to server" << endl;
        SetConnected(true);

        socket.setBlocking(false);

        sf::Packet& operator <<(sf::Packet& packet, const PacketFormatHeader& p);
        sf::Packet& operator >>(sf::Packet& packet, PacketFormatHeader& p);

        // Receive the packet at the other end
        sf::Packet packet;
        socket.receive(packet);
        // Extract the variables contained in the packet
        _packet.opcode;
        _packet.size;
        if (packet >> _packet.opcode >> _packet.size)
        {
            cout << "Data extracted successfully" << endl;
            cout << _packet.opcode << _packet.size << endl;
        }
    }
}

void Network::SetConnected(bool i)
{
    i = this->_isConnected;
}

bool Network::GetConnected()
{
    return _isConnected;
}

void Network::RetryConnection(const sf::IpAddress &remoteAdress, int port)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sf::Socket::Status status = socket.connect(remoteAdress, port);

        if (status != sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            cout << "Retrying for connection" << endl;
            SetConnected(false);
        } else {
            cout << "Connected to server" << endl;
            SetConnected(true);
        }
    }
    MessageBoxes::Error(0, MB_OK, "Could not establish connection with the server: system exiting");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Any help i am very thankful for.

Answer (score 0):

SFML packets elements are to be read in the **same order** as the one they were written:

```
if (packet >> _packet.size >> _packet.opcode)
```

But then, you define write (<<) and read (>>) operators correctly for PacketFormatHeader, why not using them?

```
// Server code
packet << pac;

// Client code
if (packet >> _packet)
```